# VeeValidate/i18n using different languages in v4

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs3, vee-validate, vue-i18n

I've been using VeeValidate v2 and had something like this:

```
VeeValidate.Validator.localize('en', customErrors);


const customErrors = {
custom: {
  someField: {
    required: 'error.required',
  },
  ...
}}
```

I have JSON files for example en.json, de.json, fr.json, etc. which look like this:

```
// en.json
{
  "something": {
     "something1": "phrase1",
     "something2": "phrase2",
   }
  "error": {
     "required": "Field is required"
   }
}
```

In v2 this worked and errors were translated.

I updated vee-validate to v4 because of the Vue update to v3 and I don't know how to achieve the same effect.

Now I got

```
import { configure } from 'vee-validate';

// VeeValidate.Validator.localize('en', customErrors);

configure({
  generateMessage: localize('en', customErrors)
 });
```

I also changed `customErrors`

```
const customErrors = {
    fields: {
      someField: {
        required: 'error.required',
      },
      ...
    }}
```

With this config my error is just `error.required` instead of the value from this field from the JSON file.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/i18n/), the file containing the error messages should have a proper structure.

The messages should be a child of the messages data

```
messages: {
  between: 'The {field} value must be between 0:{min} and 1:{max}',
},
```